# Tabula - Selecting Columns

Tags: tabula

I set the x-coordinate to just 1 column, with a value of 1000, but the .csv file it exports has more than 1 column.

Do you know why? I have tried searching, but nothing came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have something to do with the value of the x-coordinate itself.

If you set it too low, more columns will appear. Due to "overflow".

If you set it too big, everything appears in 1 column.

I think I just solved my own problem.